# FileReference.save() documentation

Tags: actionscript-3, documentation, adobe, save, filereference

Why is the save method of the FileReference class not documented in adobe livedocs? Is the documentation just outdated? Are there any more methods/properties I should know about?

[FileReference Documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/FileReference.html)

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing something?http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save()

Comment: wth. My link doesn't have it and yours does...

Comment: !!! I have also tried your link and it worked... In any case, the link I sent you is more recent ;)

Comment: @PatrickS why not put this in an answer?

Comment: @Ryan Because I'm not sure that's a valid question. The save() method is documented... I've actually voted to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at outdated documentation. Make sure you are always looking at the latest docs.